Masonry Wall misalignment in Next.js using tailwind css
I have created an image gallery using tailwind CSS in Next.js 14.
The issue is that the description for the grid elements at the bottom of the grid moves to next column.
Solution I tried:

I used grid classes grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 for this problem but there were gaps between images which I don't want.

Current Output

My code


<div className="mt-4 columns-1 md:columns-2 lg:columns-3 gap-x-8 ">
  {ProductsMockData.map((products) => { return (
  <div className=" group relative mb-4" key={products.id}>
    <div className=" w-full overflow-hidden rounded-md bg-gray-200 lg:aspect-none group-hover:opacity-75">
      <Image src={products.image} alt="Basic Tee in black." className="h-full w-full object-cover" unoptimized={true} width={500} height={500} />
    </div>
    <div className="mt-4 flex justify-between">
      <div>
        <h3 className="text-md text-primary">
          <Link href="#">
          <span aria-hidden="true" className="absolute inset-0"></span> {products.title}
          </Link>
        </h3>
        <p className="mt-1 text-sm text-secondary-foreground">
          {products.description}
        </p>
      </div>
      <p className="text-sm font-medium text-primary">
        {products.price}
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  ); })}
</div>



Help is appreciated :)

Please consider using a formatter. If I saw it correctly you are closing the group div too early. Try to enclose the whole product (image and description) in a single div and use it for the masonry

Ok so after spending quite some time with the tailwind css documentation, I was able to find the solution to my problem.
I added class "break-inside-avoid" in <div className=" group relative mb-4" key={products.id}>, this resolved my problem.
Output achieved

No more breaking of description section at the bottom, hope this helps someone.
